# Flutter + FCM: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value: Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=100]

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notifications in a Flutter app using node.js + Typescript.

The FCM configurations for onLaunch and onResume were working fine, until I added Firebase dynamic links. Now, every time I click on a notification, the app crashes.

Error:

> Fatal: failed to find callback
> W/FirebaseMessaging(28561): Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in ?AndroidManifest. Default value will be used.
> D/AndroidRuntime(28561): Shutting down VM
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561): Process: com.muffly, PID: 28561
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value: Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=100]
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:276)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:273)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:273)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMethodCodec.encodeMethodCall(StandardMethodCodec.java:38)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.invokeMethod(MethodChannel.java:99)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.invokeMethod(MethodChannel.java:83)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.sendMessageFromIntent(FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:324)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.onNewIntent(FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:293)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onNewIntent(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:763)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.onNewIntent(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:439)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onNewIntent(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:647)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onNewIntent(FlutterActivity.java:633)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at android.app.Activity.performNewIntent(Activity.java:7935)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1407)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1420)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:3534)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:3546)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at android.app.servertransaction.NewIntentItem.execute(NewIntentItem.java:53)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2058)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7592)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28561):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
> D/OOMEventManagerFK(28561): checkEventAndDumpForJE: 0
> I/Process (28561): Sending signal. PID: 28561 SIG: 9

pubspec.yaml:

> firebase_core: ^0.5.0
>
> firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
>
> firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0-dev.15
>
> firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.0+11
>
> firebase_core: ^0.5.0

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="high_importance_channel" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Yeah, I migrated all Firebase packages in pubspec.yaml to their latest versions and it worked.